# Дообучение модели

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, бинарное-дерево, lightgbm

У меня модель (LGBMClassifier на деревьях решений) обученная на данных за период в год. Подскажите как дообучить модель (подкрутить веса и коэффициенты). Если можно ссылки на реализацию или скрипт.

Comment: Приведите ваш код и описание данных

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Последний параметр метода `fit`. Из [документации](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html):

> **fit**(X, y, sample_weight=None, init_score=None, eval_set=None,
> eval_names=None, eval_sample_weight=None, eval_class_weight=None,
> eval_init_score=None, eval_metric=None, early_stopping_rounds=None,
> verbose=True, feature_name='auto', categorical_feature='auto',
> callbacks=None, **init_model**=None)
>
> **init_model** (string, Booster, LGBMModel or None, optional
> (default=None))
> – Filename of LightGBM model, Booster instance or
> LGBMModel instance **used for continue training**.

Просто дообучаете вашу модель на свежих данных.